# PHP XML Xpath get price lower than doesn't work

Tags: php, xpath, filter, price

```
<Product>
  <Price>
   <SalePrice>
      14,95
   </SalePrice>
  </Price>
</Product>  
<Product>
  <Price>
   <SalePrice>
     16,95
   </SalePrice>
  </Price>
</Product>



$response->xpath('Product/Price/[SalePrice <= "16,95"]/parent::*
```

Hello, i wanna get every Sale Price equals or lower than 16,95 as it is in my example. But everytime i try, it gives a empty array. If i only use:

```
$response->xpath('Product/Price/[SalePrice = "16,95"]/parent::*
```

i got a result. I hope you can help me with this problem. Thanks

Comment: The error 500 is a sign that there is an error in your code, have you tried to catch the error with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ?

Comment: Escape the single quotes, or use double quotes for the encapsulation.

Comment: If you're seeing a 500 error and a blank screen, you need to [learn how to display errors or access your error log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851). Then if you still don't understand the error message, [edit] your question to include the exact wording/.

Comment: I've tried. Now it gives me a empty array.

Comment: Try this expression `Product/Price/SalePrice[text()<= '16,95']`

Comment: same with this expression

Comment: I've tried changing the expression without success. There are any other ideas?

Comment: `//Product/Price/SalePrice[number(translate(.,',','.'))<= 16.95]/parent::*`

Comment: @splash58 it work's, thank you so much!

Comment: i've written the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. translate comma to point to get correct float number
2. convert string to number
3. compare result with float number but not string

   //Product/Price/SalePrice[number(translate(.,',','.'))<= 16.95]/parent::*

[demo on eval](https://eval.in/772297)